# google MDL textfield focus to change color

Tags: html, css, material-design, material-design-lite

I just getting started this google material design lite. And i found this textfield floating when you r focusing in this label. the color is blue or navy or idk.

the problem is, I changed the link color into this color indigo-pink

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://code.getmdl.io/1.2.1/material.indigo-pink.min.css">
```

but there is no change for my textfield into an indigo color or a pink color when I focused on it.

question is simple, how to change it?

I did something with this, but still have no luck in it.

the HTML:

```
<form action="#">
  <div class="mdl-textfield mdl-js-textfield mdl-textfield--floating-label">
    <input class="mdl-textfield__input" type="text" id="sample4">
    <label class="mdl-textfield__label" for="sample3">Text...</label>
  </div>
  <div class="mdl-textfield mdl-js-textfield mdl-textfield--floating-label">
    <input class="mdl-textfield__input" type="text" pattern="-?[0-9]*(\.[0-9]+)?" id="sample4">
    <label class="mdl-textfield__label mdl-color-modifier" for="sample4">Number...</label>
    <span class="mdl-textfield__error">Input is not a number!</span>
  </div>
</form>
```

the css:

```
div .mdl-textfield__label:after {
  background: pink;
}
.mdl-textfield--floating-label .is-focused .mdl-textfield__label, .mdl-textfield--floating-label.is-dirty .mdl-textfield__label, .mdl-textfield--floating-label.has-placeholder .mdl-textfield__label{
    color:pink;
}

.mdl-color-modifier:focus{
    color:pink;
}
```

I tried to apply a new class in it with pseudo :focus, but it still have no luck too.

Comment: are you meaning of the color into which the bottom-border is switched upon focus? I believe it has something to do with javascript, since the color set on the :focus Pseudo DOES applies to the element at the instant, but above it the animation from center still recolors the border, and it even overrides the !important attribute

Comment: check my example. should work for ya. change #FAFAFA to #<whatever indigo's hex is>

Answer (score 5):

I have it all. The keys are the `:after` modifier and the `is-focused` class. Just replace `#FAFAFA` with your `indigo-pink` and it should work for ya. This is just proof of concept. Check the fiddle. it has the text label colored too.

```
.mdl-textfield.is-focused .mdl-textfield__label {
    color: #FAFAFA;
}

.mdl-textfield__label:after{
    background-color: #FAFAFA;
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/90u6Lxc4/30/

Answer (score -1):

I believe an alternate solution would be like this, it worked for me:

```
.mdl-textfield__input:focus {
    border-bottom-color: red;
    box-shadow: 0 1px 0 0 red;
}
```

I deducted the answer from [here](https://github.com/Dogfalo/materialize/issues/192).

Comment: @BillyFerguson It's working, I can see it clearly, maybe you can't see the difference because the color is white as the Background. Just change the color.

Comment: ah, take off the bootstrap link you have. it works if you remove the bootstrap, it overwrites some props on the getmdl textfield and does some wonky stuff.

Comment: Anyways it's 2 lines, if you add "bottom: 5px;" to the -focus CSS you will still see 2 lines.

Comment: Yes. I was more talking about how the two lines in your first example were mis-aligned. Without changing any code and just removing the bootstrap import in the jsfiddle it fixes that mis-alignment. I agree that what you're talking about is correct and they are, in fact, two separate lines.